# How to make label selectable with pug?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, label, pug

I have a pug mixin.  I want to use the label property to select the radio button in addition to the actual radio button itself.  Right now it only selects the first item in the list.  I think it's because pug isn't exporting plain html.  Right now the rendered html looks like this:

```
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-check">
  <input _ngcontent-c4="" checked="!{data.checked}" class="form-check-input" id="!{data.value}" name="!{data.name}" type="radio" value="!{data.value}">
  <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-check-label" for="!{data.value}">Initial Contact</label>
</div>
```

.
Instead of:

```
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-check">
  <input _ngcontent-c4="" checked="true" class="form-check-input" id="myId" name="myForm" type="radio" value="pricing}">
  <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-check-label" for="myId">Pricing Info</label>
</div>
```

.

```
 mixin formCheck(data)
        .form-check
          input.form-check-input(type='radio', name='!{data.name}', value='!{data.value}', checked='!{data.checked}', id='!{data.value}')
          label.form-check-label(for='!{data.value}') !{data.label}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 to the rescue:

```
mixin formCheck(data)
    .form-check
       input.form-check-input(type='radio', name=`${data.name}`, value=`${data.value}`, checked=`${data.checked}`, id=`${data.value}`)
       label.form-check-label(for=`${data.value}`) !{data.label}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set the values directly—without the need for string interpolation or ES6:

```
mixin formCheck(data)
  .form-check
    input.form-check-input(
      type='radio',
      name= data.name,
      value= data.value,
      checked= data.checked,
      id= data.value
    )
    label.form-check-label(
      for= data.value
    ) !{data.label}
```